# how to test a handler function which has set state method using react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I am having function called handleAge in PatientForm component..
[handleAge function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq3Vm.png)

Inside PatientForm component , i am passing that handleAge to DateField component.
[handleAge func as a prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CZ2O.png)

Inside Datefield component, i have a textfield, whenever the date is entered, it triggers the change and executes this method in onChange.calculateAge will return the year diffrence between entered date and current date, that difference is passed to handleAge, and there it will set to the state in PateintDetails component
[onChange event in DateField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfIMA.png)

now when i write a testcase like this in Datefield component
[testcase on DateField component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdAZu.png)

that line no 106 is not getting covered..
[test coverage on PatientForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Obyr.png)

that 106 line consists of setstate method
[handleAge function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nWso.png)

how to write a test to cover this method using react testing library???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post the code as text instead of screenshots and images

Answer (score 0):

instead of handleChange can you pass onChange event to your component. like this:

```js
render(<DateField label={"Date of Birth"} onChange={handleAge}/>
```

let me know whether it works or not.